# Keyboard Maestro hijacks macOS Command-Tab application switcher

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I've installed the app Keyboard Maestro on my Mac to customize keyboard shortcuts.

I press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to open the default macOS application switcher, as I always do.

But Keyboard Maestro seems to have modified the macOS app switcher to it's own custom UI:

[image: Keyboard Maestro app switcher]

> https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/5/applicationswitcher.html

How can I disable this change? I do not want to use this custom UI. I want to use the default macOS app switcher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Activate Application Switcher` macro controls this option in the default Keyboard Maestro macro rules.

Delete this macro to disable the Keyboard Maestro alternative application switcher.

[image: Activate Window Switcher macro Keyboard Maestro]

> By default, Keyboard Maestro creates a Activate Application Switcher macro in the “Switcher Group” Macro Group, triggered by Command-Tab. You can disable this Macro by selecting the Switcher Group, then selecting the Activate Application Switcher macro and clicking the ✓ button below the Macros list. You can edit this macro to change the trigger to any other desired Hot Key avoid replacing the system application switcher.
>
> https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/5/applicationswitcher.html

Personally, I believe this level of customization is far too aggressive for the *default* set of macros. It immediately puts me off using Keyboard Maestro when the app hijacks default macOS behaviors on first install.

Comment: Agreed re "too aggressive". In particular, the ctrl+tab hijacking browser tab-switching behavior for something completely unrelated was REALLY bad. I would rather get excited about the feature not frustrated by it—and there is stuff there to be excited about! easy way to quit a bunch of things: https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/documentation/5/applicationswitcher.html